# Why setInterval accepts only 2^31-1 delay values?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

According to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timers),

```
long setInterval(Function handler, optional long timeout, any... arguments);
```

`setInterval()` is supposed to accept `long` timeout delay.

However, on 64bit Linux it behaves like it was a signed 32bit int.
I didn't test on other platforms, [please try](http://jsbin.com/pefizozeci/edit?js,console) and leave a comment.

The obvious question is - *Why*?

Can someone explain **why do I get instantly output** of this:

```js
let maxSigned32 = 2147483647;
let safeInt = maxSigned32 + 1;

console.log(safeInt);
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
console.log(safeInt < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER); // true

let days = Math.round(safeInt / (1000.0 * 60 * 60 * 24));

console.log(safeInt + ' ms is ~' + days + ' days');

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('I should not see this today')
}, safeInt);
```

I get this (incorrect?) results both on Chrome 52 and Firefox 48.
Interestingly, when I built and tried with latest ChakraCore, it behaves more reasonable.

Comment: In fact, according to specification of Number: "The maximum safe integer in JavaScript (2^53 - 1)." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number,

Comment: @AndrewParamoshkin correct, it's in the snippet BTW

Comment: *"Note that the bitwise operators and shift operators operate on 32-bit ints, so in that case, the max safe integer is 2^31-1, or 2147483647."* from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: @AndrewL. I know that, but there is non of such operator used that would call EcmaScript'a defined ToInt32() conversion function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `long` type in Web IDL shouldn't be compared to its C/C++ namesake.

Its definition can be found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#idl-long):

> The **long** type is a signed integer type that has values in the range [−2147483648, 2147483647].

Comment: BTW, don't you think that measuring time in ms with signed 32int is a bit strange?

Comment: @MichałŠrajer `setInterval` isn't really meant for long-term scheduling, so having an upper limit of almost 25 days is probably regarded as being sufficient.

Comment: @robertklep html and javascript wasn't really meant for a lot of things that people are doing today :-)